# Implement search filter in recyclerview realm

Tags: android, realm

How do you implement search filter when using `RecyclerView` + `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` adapter with animations.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Toaster.make(getContext(),query);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    if(query.length()>0 && adapter!=null){

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);*/
           //this do not update the recyclerview
        realmResult = realm.where(GameListDatabase.class).equalTo("status",status).contains("name",query).findAll();

        return true;
    }


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Call notifydatachange on your RecyclerView.

Comment: You should try implementing class **Filterable** and override the `getFilter()` method. This make your filter implementation clearer. You can take a look at this article http://codetheory.in/android-filters/. It doesn't matter whether you're using RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: with animations? now that's a really good question.

Comment: I implemented Filterable and it work but is there any way to add animation like fade in / fade out  ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Filterable. This works fine for me. I kept the method "applyFilter" under Adapter, but feel free to keep it anywhere. You need to call this method whenever there is a change in the search text. "applyFilter" method calls "update" on the Adapter.

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            groupAdapter.applyFilter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });


 public void applyFilter(String searchString) {
        if (searchString == null || "".equals(searchString)) {
            realmResults = realm.where(Group.class).findAllSorted("groupName");
        } else {
            realmResults = realm.where(Group.class).contains("groupName", searchString.toString().trim()).findAllSorted("groupName");
        }
        updateData(realmResults);
    }
```